# use of 'and' and 'so' or 'therefore'?

Tags: word-choice

I'm having trouble with this sentence:

Publisher wants to use:

> Mary has two passports and so she wants to know the protocols to follow when entering and exiting certain countries.

I think:

> Mary has two passports, therefore she wants to know the protocols to follow when entering and exiting certain countries.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, although I would have put a comma after "passports" in the publisher's sentence.  Your choice sounds more formal, but the publisher's sounds more like ordinary speech to me.

Neither sentence exhibits a clear relationship between having two passports and "the protocols". If you mean to say Mary would like to use the "best" passport for each given country, maybe rephrase.